# Java: How to issue an http request asynchronously?

Tags: java, http, asynchronous, request

I've been searching around trying to find a straightforward solution to submitting an http request asynchronously in java, but haven't had any luck. I actually don't even care about the response back, I just want my client to issue the request and move on. I thought about kicking off another thread, issuing the request in the new thread, and then externally killing the thread but I'm not sure if this is even possible and even if it is, I don't think it would be very clean to forcibly kill the thread so I'm hoping there's something more elegant.

Comment: What is the point? Do not bother sending it, if you do not care if sent or not.

Comment: @Op De Cirkel - it could be a RESTful request in which the client is notifying the server of something.  Use your imagination ...

Comment: @Stephen C: you are still required to get at least the header response. In the question there is something like this: _I actually don't even care about the response back_ and another like this: _then externally killing the thread_

Comment: @Op De Cirkel - the server is required to *send* the response, but show me in the HTTP spec where it says that the client is required to *read* it.

Comment: @Stephen, my point is that if you don't wait for any resp, your request can (let say) time out (or some other bad thing can happen). So, if i don't care if the request is delivered, why bother sending it at all..... UDP is unreliable as this, but if you do UDP, you repeat the request after some time if not getting response, meaning that you always implement mechanism to make sure that things are getting done. Again, if you don't care for something, why doing it in first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start another thread. You don't need to kill it, once request is done it will just exit. Use threadpool if you have too many of those requests.

Comment: This is a good approach. If this is an infrequent operation then starting a new thread is fine, but be aware that thread creation is expensive. Using a ThreadPool is a cleaner solution and will be better if you have many requests. Just write a Runnable that sends the request and you're pretty much done.

Comment: I would have only one thread that reads a Q and does the work. the _client_ code just puts message on the Q and goes on.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Mina is a networking library atop of Java NIO. Here are some async http request code snippets, using Mina, HttpClient, NIO, etc: http://code.google.com/p/async-future/wiki/Examples

Comment: It's worth observing that [Netty](https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client) and [Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/HttpClient) (projects with two quite different aims an purposes also offer asynchronous HTTP client options.